# Emacs JavaFX Script mode?

Tags: emacs, javafx, elisp, javafx-1

Does a GNU Emacs major mode for editing JavaFX Script (JavaFX 1.x) files exist?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the answer is "no." [Want to help me write one?](http://code.google.com/p/javafxmode)